# Accessing string array list in two foreach loops

Tags: c#

so far I have done this:

```
List<string[]> VList

foreach (var item in VList)
{

    foreach (var b in item)
    {
         Richtextbox 1 = VList[item][b]?
    }
}
```

How do I do this correct? I want it to write everything that the list contains

Comment: Maybe you want to do this: RichTextbox1.text += b;

Comment: Your `foreach` loops look fine, but I don't understand what you're trying to do inside them. `item` is going to be one of the `string[]`s from your outer list, and then `b` is going to be one of the `string`s from the array; so (1) you can't use either `item` or `b` as an index, and don't need to anyway since the `foreach` already got the values out of the collections for you; and (2) you couldn't assign any of this data to a variable of type `Richtextbox`, because these aren't `Richtextbox` values, they're `string` values (and arrays and lists).

Comment: Yes I want to do +=. How can I wrote this right?

Comment: What do you want to do with that "b"?

Comment: Hans, I want it to type out everything written in the list

Answer (score 2):

A `foreach` loop iterates a collection<sup>1</sup> using an [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.8)<sup>1</sup>.
In each iteration, the loop variable (`item` and `b` in your case) references whatever the `IEnumerator.Current` property is referencing.

The square brackets `[]` are used for a special kind of property called [indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/). Indexers are typically used in a collection<sup>2</sup> to provide a reference to whatever the collection is holding that is coupled to that specific index.

When you are using a `foreach` loop, you don't need to know the index of an element in the collection - and in fact, the collection doesn't even have to support indexes - you already have a reference to it via the loop variable.

So a code that uses a nested `foreach` loop to do something with the strings inside a variable of type `List<string[]>` would be something like this:

```
foreach(var stringArray in VList)
{
    foreach(var str in stringArray)
    {
        // do something with str here...
    }
}
```

If you want to use indexers, use a `for` loop instead:

```
for(var i=0; i<VList.Count; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j<VList[i].Length; j++)
    {
        // do something with VList[i][j] here...
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, a foreach loop doesn't need an actual collection to work with.
It only needs an instance that has a method called `GetEnumerator()` that returns an object that has a public property called `Current` and a public method called `MoveNext`.
This means that even if you have a class that doesn't implement the `IEnumerable` interface but has the `GetEumerator` method, and that method returns an instance of some other class that doesn't implement the `IEnumerable` interface but has the `Current` property and the `MoveNext` method, you can still use `foreach` with that.  This is called [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

This is documented in [foreach, in (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

---

<sup>2</sup> The fact that a type has indexer doesn't have to mean that the type is a collection - it's perfectly valid to add indexres to your own type without implementing any interface collections usually implement such as `IEnumerable` or `ICollection`.

Answer (score 1):

Your access is wrong. You are iterating over the elements there is no need to use the array/indexer access. `[]`

```
List<string[]> VList

foreach (var item in VList)
{

    foreach (var b in item)
    {
         Richtextbox1.text += b
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha, so I can just write. foreach (var item in VList)
{

    foreach (var b in item)
    {
         Richtextbox 1 = b?
    }
}

Comment: b is string, you can't assign it directly to a textbox

Comment: I want to write everything the list contains, how do I do that with double foreach I have done

Comment: like the edit?  Did you mean `RichTextbox1` instead of `RichTextbox 1`? Eventhough, I've given you a direct solution I suggest you read up on what each of these symbols do.

Comment: @realme is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks I got the help needed  from your post